# Get config value to a global or const variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to assign a value from json file to a some kind of global / static variable and then use that global / static variable later down the file.

```
static $API_KEY = get_api_key(); // gives: Constant expression contains invalid operations
define('API_KEY', get_api_key()); // gives: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: API_KEY in /content.php on line 422

function get_api_key() {
    $file_content = file_get_contents("./msx/start.json");
    $json = json_decode($file_content);
    
    return $json->tmdb_api_key;
}
```

Comment: The define should work. Whats in line 422? I don't think using a static that way will ever work.

Comment: The `define` won't work. According to the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php): _"The value of the constant. In PHP 5, value must be a scalar value (int, float, string, bool, or null). In PHP 7, array values are also accepted. "_. You can't use a function in `define`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had my fingers burned by global variables several times over the years, so now I do things a different way.

Create a class for all your code, along with a `run()` method, and then you can use a class property for your 'global'.

Something like this:

```
class myClass {
    private $apiKey;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->apiKey = $this->getApiKey();
    }

    private function getApiKey() {
        $file_content = file_get_contents("./msx/start.json");
        $json = json_decode($file_content);

        return $json->tmdb_api_key;
   }

   public function run() {
   // do stuff using $this->apiKey
   }
}
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
<?php
   $p = new myClass();
   $p->run();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I find it a bit radical change to move everything into a class just to accommodate such a  small issue. I'm not a big fan of the whole class OOP notion.

Comment: I incorporated your suggestion and it was not that much of a problem, and as a side product I got rid of all the GLOBAL variables. Thanks for your answer.